# Do HTML marquee tags will run in the background even when hidden?

Tags: html, marquee

I am in support of an old project which gives Awsnapp issue often in google chrome. We suspected it to be due to marquee tag running all time. But my question is if the marque tag is hidden with below code will it still run in process in the background?

```
<marquee onmouseover="this.stop();" onmouseout="this.start();" style="position: absolute;top: 75%;left: 0;z-index: 150;font-family: initial;color: black;" id="scrolltext" behavior="scroll" direction="left" ng-hide="views.showview" hidden="hidden"><div> Text Scrolls here </div></marquee>
```

Comment: Please use ng-if instead of ng-hide to remove this from DOM then it will not run in the background.

Comment: This seems like something it should be easy to test on your own. Create a simple `marquee` that takes a specific amount of time to run through start to finish. Start it. hide it for part of the time. Show it. See if the time elapsed from start to finish is the same as when you don't hide it.

Comment: This may also vary between browsers/browser versions, I would suggest not relying on consistent behaviour if you can avoid it.